# How to use the "sed" command to remove all lines that do not end up on the pattern?

Tags: sed, text-editing

How to use the "sed" command to remove all lines that do not end up on the pattern?

Example input:

```
aaa aaa.com
b b b b.txt
ccc ccc.gif
dd dd dd.txt
```

Looking for the pattern `.txt`,

I want to get:

```
b b b b.txt
dd dd dd.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed '/.txt/!d' test.txt
```

or to replace it in your file

```
sed -i '/.txt/!d' test.txt
```

but why dont you use a simple

```
grep  \.txt test.txt
```

here?

Comment: I'm doing something wrong.

`sed '/.txt/!d' $pn          

printf '%s\n' "$pn" | while IFS= read -r line
do
   printf "$line\n"
done`